# postgresql INSERT INTO with IF statement

Tags: postgresql

In `postgresql`, how to `INSERT` values in a **column.b** from **column.a** from same table Where

```
IF column.a = 1 then column.b = foo, 
IF column.a = 2 then column.b = bar,
IF column.a = 3 then column.b = good,
IF column.a = 4 then column.b = bad
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the row already exists, you do not need an `INSERT`. You need an `UPDATE` like this:

```
UPDATE your_table
SET b = CASE 
        WHEN a = 1 then 'foo'
        WHEN a = 2 then 'bar'
        WHEN a = 3 then 'good'
        ELSE 'bad'
        END
WHERE some_condition = 'true';
```

Answer (score 5):

INSERT does not insert values into columns. It inserts new rows into your table. Instead, you need to use an [UPDATE statement](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-update.html). You will also need some [ifs inside](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-conditional.html).